OpenApi 3 spring server generator docs
I'm looking for a complete and extensive documentation regarding the directive, the data type, the structure and everything about how to write a .yaml file to generate a Spring server.
Googling around I found this docs but is not what I'm looking for. There is no info regarding the structure of the file, the data type are all with the first letter capitalized and so on... Where can I find something like that?

Do you mean something like this? https://swagger.io/docs/specification/v3_0/basic-structure/

Yes yes can be usefull thank you. Anyway I'm writing my own docs using ChatGPT. Thanks again
